# Return processed DB data at once using class method

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, recordset

I have a class which is supposed to load an article with a given ID from a database. It returns a recordset with the requested database row. It's working well, but sometimes I would like to attach an additional column. However, I can only change the value of an already-existing column. Something like this:

```
article("imageID") = getImageURL(article("imageID"))
```

This way, I have rewritten image ID by it's URL.

But let's say I want to return both the ID and URL. From what I've found, it's not possible to append a column to recordset when it's already filled by data from the DB. One solution is to use a class variable, but I am looking for a way to return all the data at once (not dividing them into recordset and class variables), because there would be too many variables like this in my case and I don't think it's clean anyway. So what's the best other way to do it then?

Here is my current code:

```
public property get getRecordSet()
    set article = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")        
    article.open "SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = '" & articleId & "'", db, 2, 3

    if not data.eof then
        // This formats some values, so I can directly use them when returned

        article("imageID") = getImageURL(article("imageID"))
        article("date") = getFormatedDate(article("date"))

        // imageID and date are rewritten now, so I can't access
        // their original values anymore

        // But instead of above, I would like to keep imageID and date
        //   and return their processed values as well.
        //     As follows (but it's not the correct working way):

        article("imageURL") = getImageURL(article("imageID"))
        article("formatedDate") = getFormatedDate(article("date"))
    end if

    // Return recordset
    set getRecordSet = article
end property
```

Comment: Why is this tagged both asp.net & asp-classic?  It usually is one or the other unless you have a mixture of pages (which you have not indicated is the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you need to return a recordset? It looks like you're just returning values for a single row. If you need to add additional information, you're kind of breaking the recordset contract anyway. You could return an array or a dictionary just as easily.

For example, if you had a `getDictionary()` property instead:

```vb
Public Property Get getDictionary()

    set article = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")        
    article.open "SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = '" & articleId & "'", db, 2, 3

    Set getDictionary = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    getDictionary.Add "imageID", article("imageID")
    getDictionary.Add "imageURL", getImageURL(article("imageID"))
    getDictionary.Add "date", article("date")
    getDictionary.Add "formatedDate", getFormatedDate(article("date"))

End Property
```

Then you could use it like so:

```vb
Response.Write someObject.getDictionary.Item("imageURL")
```

Comment: No need to return a recordset. Any other form which doesn't divide data is accaptable. This one is fine, but it requires one line of code for each column I want to return. Would it be possible to dynamicaly transform column names in DB into array / dictionary names, so there will be no need of using getDictionary.Add "columnName" for each column ? Also, even though the example I wrote returns one row only, I would like to use this solution for multiple row cases as well.

Comment: @user2779059 `data = article.GetRows()` will return `data` as a 2-dimensional array of columns and rows.

Comment: If you need to return data for multiple rows, an array may be a better solution. As @Lankymart mentioned above, `GetRows()` can get you from a `Recordset` to an array in no time. You can `ReDim` a multidimensional array in VBScript, but only in the last dimension. But that should be what you need anyway (to add additional columns). So `GetRows()` + `ReDim` may be your best option. You just lose the ability to retrieve column values by name.

Comment: BTW, to answer your other question, yes, you could just loop over the columns (`For Each col In article.Fields`) to get each field name and value, which are the two things you need to add the info to a dictionary. So you could construct a simple loop to transfer from `Recordset` to `Dictionary`.

Comment: Using array would be a working solution, but since classes are stored away from other code, the code would lose easy readability. So I definitely need to retrieve them by name. Dictionaries seems fine to me and suggestion to loop over columns and add values to dictionary would work, but that's only a solution to a single-row cases. Am I right?